# Is it safe to stand near the microwave oven while it operates?

Tags: cancer, radiation, bioelectromagnetics, microwaves

My son told me that it's possible to test whether your microwave oven is properly insulated by putting a cell phone into the oven, closing the door, and then calling that phone. We did this, and the phone inside the oven rang, supposedly proving that the oven was not properly insulated.

Today I looked at [an article about microwave ovens](https://www.webmd.com/food-recipes/what-to-microwave-ovens-health), and I don't really follow it. At one point I understood it to say that microwave ovens are like conventional ovens, in that if an oven is badly insulated, someone standing by could be burned (although not exposed to cancer risk). I thought that since I never feel the oven heating me when I stand near it, and it never burns me, there is nothing to worry about. But then the article said that "If you have an older microwave you want to hold on to, it might be best not to remain in the same room while it’s cooking. This is just to protect you from any potential radiation leakage."

What? It's "just" to protect me from radiation leakage? Why is this wise, if I can plainly see that I'm not getting burned and therefore not exposed to radiation?

Comment: That article answers your question completely. What about it do you not understand?

Comment: Out of curiosity I tried your son's microwave test with 3 microwaves I have access to. All are high-quality, modern units and all carried UL marks indicating they have been tested and approved by Underwriter's Laboratories. That's a good indication they are safe. The phone rang in all three, so I don't think your son's test has any validity. But if you want to be sure, I would delete this question here and post it in Electrical Engineering.SE where it's more on topic. It isn't really a medical sciences question.

Comment: It may help if you were to show your prior research when posting there. I suggest looking-up the frequency of 5G and comparing it with a household microwave magnetron.

Comment: @Carey Gregory As I said, I don't see how "it might be best not to remain in the same room while it’s cooking. This is just to protect you from any potential radiation leakage." We seem to have said that there's no danger, and then to conclude with a strategy for dealing with this danger.

Comment: I agree, it's a little silly for it to have been written that way - more pandering to sensitive feelings than a practical safety tip it seems. Patronising, infantilising perhaps.

Comment: Keep in mind it's on WebMD, which isn't a scientific journal. The content is written by content creators, not doctors or scientists. I've done some content creation, and I wrote articles about subjects I knew next to nothing about. The client would give me a topic and I would do some research and write a couple of pages about it. A subject matter expert would review my article before publication just like this one was, but those reviews are very superficial. The doctor who reviewed that article would simply skim it and look for factual errors. Finding misleading writing wasn't his job.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about medical science.